# Passing and testing function with jquery and jasmine

Tags: jquery, jasmine, bdd

How do I test my following jquery function -

```
function checkExpirationDate(){
var today = new Date();
var expirationDate = new Date($("#expirationYear").val(), $("#expirationMonth").val());
return today >= expirationDate;
```

}

I have no clue how it to call this function from jasmine and pass those #expirationYear and #expirationMonth values.

Comment: You need to refactor the function to make it testable (better). Check out [this article](http://alistapart.com/article/writing-testable-javascript). If you have to use this, try [spying](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Spies) on `$`

Answer (score 1):

To just test that one function will be hard since it's just the one function but let's say that you could encapsulate it into some DateHandling object then testing that would be easier.

Let's start!

```
var DateHandler = function() {
    this.checkExpirationDate = function(year, month) {
        //Do date check here
        return true;        
    }
}

#from your jasmine spec

describe("DateHandler", function() {
    it("checks the expiration date", function() {
        var dateHandlerInstance = new DateHandler();
        var isDateExpired = dateHandlerInstance.checkExpirationDate("2013", "03");
        expect(isDateExpired).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Disclaimer: Didn't test this as I'm not on my development machine. :)

Comment: Is there a way I could do that without having handling object. One of my other function calls this one.

Comment: Yeah, if you just make that function global in your test then you can do whatever you want but I would really urge you to use that object! :)

Comment: I was able to solve this. Thanks @limelights for help.
`describe("check expiration date", function() {
  it("for valid card expiry selection", function() {
   var expirationYear = $('<input type="text" id="expirationYear" value="2020">');
   var expirationMonth = $('<input type="text" id="expirationMonth" value="16">');
   var result = expiredExpirationDate.call(expirationYear,expirationMonth);
   expect(result).toBe(false);
  });
 });`